# redefine xsd element throws "not well formed" error

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, soapui, w3c

I am trying to use the element redefine in my xsd. I have tried different combinations but still don't seem to get this error resolved. The error shows up when i try to load the WSDL including the redefined schema into SOAP UI. Also, it doesnt show up in the design for the xsd in eclipse.

WSDL -> Imports TestService.xsd -> Imports CreateTest.xsd -> Contains a definition of CreateTestRequestType.

When i load this into my SOAPUI, everything looks good and no errors.

Now, I am trying to redefine the type ***CreateTestRequestType*** in another xsd called ***CreateRedefineTest.xsd*** and import this xsd into the TestService.xsd (The import statement is comemented, but i necessarily just uncomment this import and comment the other one for testing). But when i load the WSDL into SOAP UI, i get the below error:

```
Source: null Error: URL "CreateTest.xsd" is not well-formed
```

***EDIT1:*** 
I am able to resolve this error by giving an absolute path. Is it possible to make it work with relative path?

***EDIT2***
I looked at w3 article about this element and the example does use a relative path. But i tried to replicate but it still doesnt work. The example is available at the this [location](http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/Redefine/).

I think i am missing some rule, but i have tried multiple things and dont seem to be able to resolve this.

Below is the source code for the WSDL and XSD's.

WSDL:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions
 xmlns:test="http://test.com/TESTServices/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:tes="http://test.com/TestService/Test/"
 name="TestService"
 targetNamespace="http://test.com/TESTServices/">

 <wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://test.com/TestService/Test/">
   <xsd:include schemaLocation="TestService.xsd" />
  </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
 
 <!-- Create Test -->
 <wsdl:message name="CreateTestRequest">
  <wsdl:part element="tes:CreateTestRequest" name="parameters" />
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="CreateTestResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="tes:CreateTestResponse" name="parameters" />
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="TESTHeader">
  <wsdl:part name="request_header" element="tes:testHeader"/>
 </wsdl:message>

 <wsdl:message name="TestFault">
  <wsdl:part name="testFault" element="tes:testFault"></wsdl:part>
 </wsdl:message>


 <wsdl:portType name="TestServices_v4_0">
  <!-- Create Party -->
  <wsdl:operation name="CreateTest">
   <wsdl:input message="test:CreateTestRequest" />
   <wsdl:output message="test:CreateTestResponse" />
   <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="test:TestFault"></wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType>

 <wsdl:binding name="TestServicesSOAP_v4_0" type="test:TestServices_v4_0">
  <soap:binding style="document"
   transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  
  <!-- Create Party -->
  <wsdl:operation name="CreateTest">
   <soap:operation soapAction="http://firstniagara.com/PartyService/CreateTest" />
   <wsdl:input>
    <soap:header message="test:TESTHeader" part="request_header"
     use="literal" />
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output>
    <soap:header message="test:TESTHeader" part="request_header"
     use="literal" />
    <soap:body use="literal" />
    
   </wsdl:output>
   <wsdl:fault name="fault">
    <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal" />
   </wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding>

 <wsdl:service name="TestServices_v4_0">
  <wsdl:port binding="test:TestServicesSOAP_v4_0" name="TestServicesSOAP">
   <soap:address location="http://localhost/TEST/ESB" />
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This WSDL Imports ***TestService.xsd***, which contains below code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:ct="http://test.com/TestService/CreateTest/"
 targetNamespace="http://test.com/TestService/Test/"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">

 <xsd:import namespace="http://test.com/TestService/CreateTest/" schemaLocation="CreateTest.xsd" />

<!--  <xsd:import namespace="http://test.com/TestService/CreateTest/" schemaLocation="CreateRedefineTest.xsd" /> -->
 
 <!-- CreateParty -->
 <xsd:element name="CreateTestRequest" type="ct:CreateTestRequestType" />
 <xsd:element name="CreateTestResponse" type="ct:CreateTestResponseType" />

 <xsd:element name="testHeader" type="xsd:string" />
 <xsd:element name="testFault" type="xsd:string" />
 
 
 
</xsd:schema>
```

**TestService.xsd** contains ***CreateTest.xsd***, which contains the below code and has a type ***CreateTestRequestType*** defined:

```html
<xsd:schema 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="http://test.com/TestService/CreateTest/"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
 

 <!--  Create Test-->
 <xsd:complexType name="CreateTestRequestType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="RequestId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="TestRecord" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="CreateTestResponseType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="RequestId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Messages" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="TestIdentifier" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>   
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 
</xsd:schema>
```

Trying to redefine **CreateTestRequestType** in CreateRedefineTest.xsd as below:

```html
<xsd:schema 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:cp="http://test.com/TestService/CreateTest/"
 targetNamespace="http://test.com/TestService/CreateTest/"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
 
  <xsd:redefine schemaLocation="CreateTest.xsd">
  <xsd:complexType name="CreateTestRequestType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="cp:CreateTestRequestType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:redefine> 

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I don't know if there is some error in XMLBeans (it's the framework which SOAPUI it's using to load the WSDL and the xsds) with `<xs:redefine>`. The thing is if I use an absolute path for `schemaLocation` in `xs:redefine` using the follow notation `file:///C:/Path_to_xsd` seems that non error is thrown an the WSDL is load. However then when I create the request and add manually the new element `<country>` and I validate the request with SOAPUI it says that element is not allowed. So with the full path wsdl loads without error but loads incorrectly... hope you'll be lucky finding a solution.

Comment: @albciff, Thanks for looking at this and trying. I tried to use the absolute path and it works and loads with the expected elements and validates OK. I used "/" instead of "\" and it worked fine.  Now, i need to figure out how to make it work using relative path. Thanks a lot for trying this!

Comment: it's great that my comment helps you `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapUI is a great tool which has helped me through out and will keep helping me in future in great ways.

I think this is one of the feature which apparently a lot of users don't use and seems to be a bug in SoapUI 5.0.0. I tried the same thing in a couple older versions of SoapUI and got the same result. I also tried it in a Trial version of SOAP UI NG Pro 1.2.2.

I then tried this in XMLSpy and it worked without any errors, exact same xsd's with no modification. (Note: the TestService.xsd needs the commented import statement for Redefined.xsd)

I also found there was a bug reported, but didn't find a resolution or any comments about the resolution. If someone would like the references of these bugs, the [location](https://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/651/). You can look up the bugs 651, 586 and 539 which are related if you wish.

I hope at some point this bug is fixed in SoapUI. 
I also created a new bug to refer to these old bugs and consolidate: [SourceForge 671](http://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/671/)

And hope this post saves other's time if they run into the same problem.

Thanks all for everyone who looked at this post.

Answer (score 1):

I want to confirm that I get the same error above when trying to use the xsd:redefine element in my message set with version 5.0.0 of SOAP UI.

Basically, I have to extend the message definition of another the message set defined by the Open Geospatial Group - Web Feature Service and use the redefined schema in the request and response definition of my WSDL.

In addition to the 'not well-formed' error, I also get:

`'Source: null Error: type 'QueryType@http://www.opengis.net/wfs' not found.'`

Eclipse doesn't have a problem with the WSDL validation and I can import it into Rational Service Tester (V8.5.0.2) without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your parser not being able to locate the schema document for "cp:http://test.com/TestService/CreateTest/".
Does this still occur if you use absolute URL for the cp xsd, or use an XML Catalog?